# Can Pantheon's ult dodge Karthus' ult?

Tags: league-of-legends

Can Pantheon dodge Karthus' ult while in the air from his own ult?
Also, can other champions dodge it with their abilities, such as Fizz's <kbd>E</kbd>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike Fizz, Pantheon's Grand Skyfall imparts no kinds of invulnerability. Case in point: if Pantheon ults on top of Viktor's Gravity Field, he will get stunned *before* landing.

Pantheon is unable to be selected by targeted abilities, due to not being physically on the map, but any AoE effects, including Reqiuem (Karthas' Ult) will have no trouble dealing damage.

Answer (score 2):

OLD question, but I've wondered the same thing after seeing this clip:

Pantheon can dodge Karthus ultimate.